# Design pattern for a task which involves subtasks

Tags: design-patterns

The task is, Given a list of files, for each file do some processing (sub-tasks) like encoding and encrypting.

In the following implementation, I used Composition where `MultiFileProcessor` uses `FileEncryptionService` and `FileEncoderService`, The problems I can think of with this design are

- `MultiFileProcessor` is dependent on concrete implementations of sub-task implementations and is tightly coupled
- In the future, if I need to add another sub-task, I need to make changes in `MultiFileProcessor` class

```java
public class MultiFileProcessor {
    FileEncryptionService fileEncryptionService;
    FileEncoderService fileEncoderService;

    public MultiFileProcessor(FileEncoderService encoderService, FileEncryptionService encryptionService) {
        fileEncryptionService = encryptionService;
        fileEncoderService = encoderService;
    }

    public void processFiles(File[] files) {
        for (File file : files) {
            fileEncoderService.encode(file);
            fileEncryptionService.encrypt(file);
        }
    }
}

class FileEncryptionService {
    void encrypt(File file) { /*encrypt here*/}
}

class FileEncoderService {
    void encode(File file) { /*encode here*/}
}
```

How can I change my design to overcome these drawbacks? Any inputs are highly appreciated...

Comment: To the down-voters: don't get too hung up on the question title. Normally "what design pattern can I use" questions are opinion-based, but the OP clearly states the drawbacks and is looking for advice on how to mitigate them. Both questions posed here are related, so I don't believe this question needs focus, either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an abstract base class (or interface) for subtasks. Make each subtask inherit from that.

Give the MultiFileProcessor a list of subtasks. It can then execute each subtask in order.

Comment: Until there is a clear relationship between these processors, I would recommend an interface. This, of course, only applies to languages that support interfaces.